# In golfing terms should Ambrose be upper- or lowercase?

Tags: capitalization

Is the *Ambrose* type of play named after someone and therefore uppercase?

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue of capitalization of eponyms is inherently ambiguous, e.g. you can perform a *herculean* task, but you might get *Parkinson's* disease. The general trend seems to be that you capitalize the eponym, but not its auxiliary words (like *disease* above) or words derived from the eponym. Further, capitalization wanes after the eponym comes into common use. *Ambrose* is a little bit of a tricky case, since it is commonly used, but relatively recent, and only used within a particular subset of the English-speaking world. I would think that this places it pretty squarely in *Do Capitalize* territory.

If it really bothers you, you can always skirt the issue by calling it a *scramble*.

Comment: A major factor, I think, is parallel usage with non-capitalized terms.  Eponymous skating jumps are lowercase to allow for consistent capitalization of jumps in a sequence, though one can well imagine non-eponymous ones having become uppercase instead (with "Toe Loop" referring to a particular jump, as opposed to any maneuver where a toe performs a loop).

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search reveals:

- It is evidently named after someone (a couple, apparently)
- It *is* written using upper-case, except on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf#Team_play)

[image]

Comment: If you Google without the word "scramble" in your search terms (i.e. Ambrose golf), you get 1,270,000 results.

Comment: Thanks for the note! Very helpful.  Still, I'm surprised that it goes from 1.2 million to less than 10.

Comment: @JLG They’ve changed the algorithm.  `golf +Ambrose` now gives only 73 hits; `golf scramble +Ambrose` gives 28 hits.  No more five-order-of-magnitude difference.

Answer (score 0):

It would be with an uppercase A because it is a name. (Ambrose)

Comment: ..Just like ohm.