# Capitalization of words derived from proper nouns

Tags: nouns, orthography, capitalization

Should words derived from proper nouns be capitalized or not?  e.g. "Romanize/romanize", "Boolean/boolean" (I have seen both forms in the corpora and dictionaries).

Personally I think the derived words are not proper (they refer to a concept rather than a person) and should not be capitalized.

Comment: In the first instance, words –  adjectives, at least –  derived directly from proper nouns are capitalised (eg English; Edwardian; Parisian). Over time, such words may become genericised, especially when Boole say has been dead for some time. There's often a choice, but it's best to check in a dictionary or two.

Comment: If only other languages agreed but the rules differ from English to French to German etc. For example, in French the word *français* means different things according to whether it is capitalized or not. *Un Français ne parle pas forcément le français* means a Frenchman doesn't necessarily speak French.

Comment: @KCH Whereas in Spanish, the lowercase version (like *español, francés, alemán*, etc.) serves for both language and person.  You only capitalize it in titles or organizations, like in the *Real Academia Española*, where you necessarily also capitalize other words. [“La Real Academia **Española** (RAE) es una institución cultural con sede en Madrid. Junto con otras veintiuna academias correspondientes a sendos países donde se habla **español**, conforman la Asociación de Academias de la Lengua **Española.”**](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Academia_Espa%C3%B1ola)

Comment: @tchrist French is particularly maddening when it comes to capitalization, for example the name of the country *La République française* small 'f'! But when adjectives precede the noun they get capitalized!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But time is no guarantee of a vanishing majuscule; the *diesel engine* and the *teddy bear* postdate *Machiavellian schemes* and *Gordian knots* by centuries.

Comment: Somewhat related: *[In golfing terms should Ambrose be upper- or lowercase?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64539)*.

Answer (score 5):

Etymology is not a determiner of whether something gets capitalized or not. Many proper nouns are derived from non-proper nouns (e.g. *Apple, Smith, United Kingdom, World Wide Web*), and vice versa (e.g. *atlas, echo, narcissist, siren, sodomy*). It is usage and usage alone that determines whether something gets capitalized or not.

This is decided for each and every word individually. And it is decided not by a committee in a single sitting on a given date, but by millions of people all over the world over the course of decades or even centuries.

As a result, there is no general pattern. The Roman Empire had nothing whatsoever to do with George Boole, after all. However, there can be a clear pattern for words of the same group, for obvious reasons. For example, the days of the week, the months, and the names of languages are always capitalized regardless of whether or not they were derived from proper or common nouns. Conversely, genericized trademarks (*aspirin, bandaid, coke, escalator, kleenex, thermos, zipper*) are no longer capitalized, even though they were *specifically invented* to be capitalized at all times ever.

Lastly, while capitalized nouns and adjectives are quite common in English, it simply does not like to capitalize verbs anywhere as much. So it is safe to say that even if we collectively try really hard to Google for Photoshopped cats in order to LOL, we will eventually end up googling for photoshopped cats and lolling.

See also: [Should the word "Boolean" be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/should-the-word-boolean-be-capitalized)

Comment: I think parallel usage with non-eponymous terms is a major factor in capitalization; skating jumps are comparatively recent inventions, but it would be somewhat awkward to mix upper and lowercase when discussing e.g. a combination triple Lutz and double flip.  If Gordian knots were frequently tied in combination with e.g. square knots, they'd probably be lowercase as well, but since they're something very different, it makes sense for their orthography to be different as well.

Comment: Note that some of those "genericized trademarks" are still in force as legal trademarks. Band-Aid, Fibreglas, and Styrofoam are famous examples, and should be capitalized (and ownership acknowledged) even if common usage is as a generic. At least, that should preclude any annoying letters from their owners' legal departments. Aspirin is specifically in the public domain, as it was seized as enemy property from a German company (Bayer) during WWI.

Comment: "It is usage and usage alone that determines whether something gets capitalized or not." This is quite a bold claim to be left uncited. Of course, usage has the final say. If a grammatical rule dictate a certain spelling [A], but everyone spells it a different way [B], then [B] is correct. However, that grammatical rule will still be in effect for many equivalent cases. [B] is the exception, [A] is the rule. So, to say etymology doesn't matter is incorrect. https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9Yk5QGXu4S3I.html

Comment: I landed here while researching a problem. Currently there is an extremely loud discussion in the blind community about whether to capitalize Braille as the code name. We, the "pro-cap" people, argue that we capitalize Morse code, degrees Celsius and so on. However, being a "pro-cap", I'm extremely reluctant to capitalize Braille as a verb (meaning to write in Braille or to transcribe to Braille, as in "I brailled this recipe for you" or "I like brailling on my iPhone instead of using the virtual keyboard"). I don't cap "to google" either. What's your answer to this, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The difference between Boolean and boolean becomes distinct in computer languages, such as Java. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3728616/509840.

In Java, *Boolean* refers to an Object, which may be true, false, or null. In contrast, *boolean* refers to a primitive type, which may only be true or false.

I am guessing that the OP is deciding between *Boolean* and *boolean* in the context of mathematics or computers. Most of the mathematical references I'm seeing (Wikipedia, Wolfram) for [Boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic) or [Boolean algebra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BooleanAlgebra.html) capitalized the word.

Comment: The facts that OP (1) asks generally 'Should words derived from proper nouns be capitalized or not?' (2) includes 'Romanize / romanize as well as Boolean/boolean (3) posts on a general English language site _argue against_ his delimiting to the maths / computer domain. This is a good comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are of two different types.  Boolean is named after George Boole, a specific person.  Therefore **Boolean** should be capitalized.

In common usage, Romanize, frequently appears in lower case.  I don't know if "common usage" equates to "being correct"

Comment: The OED has *romanize* for the verb, with an initial lowercase, but its citations are often using the uppercase version. When one uses *romanize* to mean to convert some piece of writing into the Roman — that is, Latin — alphabet, we have a verb that comes from an adjective that comes from the name of the Eternal City herself. However, uppercase verbs like *Africanize*, *Latinize*, *Italianize*, and *Hellenize* also exist. Note that in typography, a *roman face* opposes an *italic face*, where both are written without an initial uppercase letter. Most people write of *googling things* in lc.

Comment: @tchrist  If YOU were to use *Romanize* in a sentence would you capitalize it??

Comment: I do find something I once wrote wherein I say “typically we now Romanize *zeta* to *x* in Greek words”, but there at least I chose to make the Greek and Roman scripts parallel in capitalization, and I could not downcase *Greek*.

Comment: I'd note that *draconian laws*, *chauvinist views*, *silhouetted forms*, and *lesbian lovers* are both eponymous and uncapitalized, so I think your statement is somewhat oversimplifying matters.

Comment: @choster  My question is:  Does a "rule" exist or not??  Is there only a general guideline and millions of exceptions??  If I remove may Readers cap and put on an Editor's cap, when do I reach for the red pen??  Must I consult  with Ngrams to see which spelling was most popular last year??    If RegDwight is correct, making a specific style guide would be difficult.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent With virtually any rule of any living language, the exceptions take up five times as much space as the rule itself— consider how many threads we've had on articles with proper nouns. I would venture that the more the average person associates an eponym with its namesake, the more likely it is to remain capitalized. For instance, *Don Juan* and *Syphilis* were popularized in English as characters in poems. But the latter association is largely forgotten, and so it is that Don Juans (and *[C/c]asanovas* and *[L/l]otharios*) catch *syphilis*, not *Syphilis*.

Comment: " 'Boolean' is named after George Boole. Therefore 'Boolean' should be capitalized." Do _you_ write 'Ohms'? I'd guess not. Your statement is not 'somewhat oversimplifying matters', it's inaccurate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  The more I dig, the more I realize that your first comment to the OP was accurate......... *" it's best to check in a dictionary or two"*

Comment: Not totally accurate :-) I missed out 'recently revised'.

Answer (score 0):

I think generally capitalizing would make it more specific and proper, however a lower-case would do as well.

Browsing around, lots of words like anglicize have alternate forms like Anglicize. However, words like Latinize are generally always uppercase, but romanize is generally lower-case.

I think a hard and fast rule would be always to capitalize to clarify to your audience that the words are derived from proper noun roots.

Comment: I've never seen 'Galvanise'.

Comment: Could you please supply references for this position?

Comment: Neither have I seen "Boycott" capitalized, except in reference to the eponymous Captain Charles Boycott. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boycott

Comment: And *"lynch"* is generally lowercase as well.

Comment: We measure electricity in volts and amperes (lower case), although their _symbols_ are V and A (capitalized). Both Volta and Ampere were proper names of real people.